# automatic utility pump for basement

Tags: water, basement, pump

I am looking for an automatic backup pump to put directly on the floor of my unfinished basement, not in a sump. Is there a pump that will sit on the basement floor and turn on automatically if it senses a few inches of water, and then turn off when the water level drops to about 1/8th inch? I understand that Zoeller has a pump like this, but it turns on automatically every 3 minutes, even if there is no water.  They told me that it should not be left plugged after the water is gone, because it would eventually burn out from running dry.  I need something that will only turn on when it senses a few inches of water, and then will turn off and remain off when the water is gone. Must have a garden hose attachment.

Comment: Search for flood sensors, you may find something that will be able to turn the pump on or off.

Comment: Why would you not install it in your sump basin? Staggered-height backups are standard practice.

Comment: Here in the northeastern US, pumps are available in every hardware store with float switches or equivalent. Have you tried going in and shopping the shelves?

Answer (score 1):

You might try a "pedestal pump" instead of a "submerged pump", but they're both listed as a "sump pump".

You'd probably have to adjust the float, maybe by swapping out the float rod with a longer one, to get the float that close to the ground so that it will trigger sooner.

If you want a garden hose output, you'll probably have to come up with a collection of adapters to get down from the 1-1/2 or 1-1/4" standard pipe output to a smaller level.

Or, as was suggested in a comment, use the pump you've found, a water sensor, a smart plug and some automation to turn the pump on when the sensor identifies water at your desired level, then turns the pump off when it's fallen below the desired level. You might need two water sensors - a higher "turn on" sensor and a lower "turn off" sensor.

Answer (score 1):

A [puddle pump](https://www.tsurumipump.com/lsc-series/) with a [surface level switch](https://www.tsurumipump.com/accessory-surface-level-switch-sls-lsc/twsps20/) will do it. Make sure that the pump is at the lowest point and the switch at the same, or slightly higher, elevation. You don't want the switch at the lowest point lest it run the pump dry.